# How to explicitly deactivate Razor code

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I follow this pattern quite a bit using Razor:

```
@if (Model.IsAlreadyConfirmed)
{
     This account has already been confirmed.
}
```

But this doesn't work because it's expecting code. I'm forced to do something like this:

```
@if (Model.IsAlreadyConfirmed)
{
     @Html.Raw("This account has already been confirmed.")
}
```

Or this:

```
@if (Model.IsAlreadyConfirmed)
{
    <span>This account has already been confirmed.</span>
}
```

Also, feel free to correct my improper use of jargon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@if (Model.IsAlreadyConfirmed)
{
     <text>This account has already been confirmed.</text>
}
```

There is a special tag called text that only prints out what you put in it.  The actual tag is omitted in the rendered html.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively to the `<text>` tag, you can also preface your line with `@:`

```
@if (Model.IsAlreadyConfirmed)
{
     @:This account has already been confirmed.
}
```